# Is there a way to use users' cloud storage for a notes app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web-applications, cloud-storage

I am building a notes desktop app using NextJS and Tauri. I am trying to create cloud sync feature which allows the user to store and retrieve the notes created in and from their cloud storage (any of Google Cloud, One drive, etc). How do I achieve this?

I couldn't find any way to use the users' cloud.

Answer (score 0):

So, you'll need a way of storing the user authentication on that specific cloud (it could be an oAuth or an API key), then use this key to fetch/store stuff on their cloud.

Each cloud has a specific API so you probably want them to let you know before (with a select input probably) which is the cloud they are trying to connect to, and proceed for the authentication.

In Next.JS after storing this authentication somewhere (probably a database) you can fetch for this in a private API bound by user's id/email whatever... There is no special magic on doing this, you just need to read about each cloud you want to support API to understand how to interact with them properly.

I recommend you checking [this doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js) from google to understand a little bit more about the implementation of it as one of the many you'll need to read/understand in order to support those clouds on your platform.